# Where do I need to URL-encode POST data?

Tags: ruby, http, urlencode

Where should I URL-encode my POST request data? For each param, or for the whole query line?

For example, I have this code:

```
@VIEWSTATE = url_encode(@VIEWSTATE)
data = ("__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=#{@VIEWSTATE}&__EVENTVALIDATION=#{@EVENTVALIDATION}&=ctl0.......
headers = {
  'Cookie' => cookie,
***
}

resp, data = http.post(path, data, headers)
```

Is it right, or must I write:

```
@VIEWSTATE = @VIEWSTATE
    data = url_encode("__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=#{@VIEWSTATE}&__EVENTVALIDATION=#{@EVENTVALIDATION}&=ctl0.......
    headers = {
      'Cookie' => cookie,
    ***
    }

    resp, data = http.post(path, data, headers)
```

Which is right, and which is better?

Comment: You shouldn't have an instance variable named `@VIEWSTATE`. local, @instance and @@class variables are written in snake_case. CONSTANTS are upper-case only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally like to use [URI's `encode_www_form`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form) which takes either an array or a hash of name/value pairs. This is the example from [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form):

```
require 'uri'

URI.encode_www_form([["q", "ruby"], ["lang", "en"]])
#=> "q=ruby&lang=en"
URI.encode_www_form("q" => "ruby", "lang" => "en")
#=> "q=ruby&lang=en"
URI.encode_www_form("q" => ["ruby", "perl"], "lang" => "en")
#=> "q=ruby&q=perl&lang=en"
URI.encode_www_form([["q", "ruby"], ["q", "perl"], ["lang", "en"]])
#=> "q=ruby&q=perl&lang=en"
```